# How to in-app purchase more than one product item (in Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app

[`in_app_purchase` docs](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#making-a-purchase) recommend the following to initiate in-app product purchase:

```dart
final ProductDetails productDetails = ... // Saved earlier from queryProductDetails().final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
if (_isConsumable(productDetails)) {
  InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
} else {
  InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
}
```

In [`ProductDetails`](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/latest/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/ProductDetails-class.html) there is no "quantity" field.

I want to sell from my app credits, one credit for one dollar, and allow the user to purchase multiple credits in one payment. Is it possible? How to indicate the amount of credits to purchase?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the Play Store allows you to specify a quantity (although I haven't used their api; I just read through the documentation). Since you are using a cross platform library you get "lowest common denominator" in terms of functionality. Even on iOS the maximum quantity you can set is 10.  Typically apps would offer different bundles as separate IAP products; a 1 credit product, a 10 credit product, a 25 credit product etc.